# Is it possible to use plastic sheeting rather than tiles in a temporary bathrooom?

Tags: shower, plastic, laminate

Is it possible to use plastic sheeting (somewhat like opaque perspex laminate) rather than tiles in a temporary (house will be demolished in two years time) bathrooom? I'm thinking the kind of product similar to what would be used in the construction of a caravan, also cheap.

It needs to meet fire safety standards.

I will fit it over plywood in one place and I'll get an electrician to fit  an electric shower unit through it.

Any suggestions ? B

Updates:

I've done some research, and what I need to get is Acrylic panel. I found a couple of UK suppliers who provide samples, for example :

http://www.rubberduckbathrooms.co.uk/index.php?main_page=advanced_search_result&search_in_description=0&zenid=22f9fb51acf432bc1fc066aea4d89e01&keyword=polyPANEL+&x=32&y=17

and

http://www.plumbase.co.uk/search?w=wall+panels

Comment: Hmmm can't say that I have ever built temporary bathroom. Not sure what that really is, but one question: since it is temporary why does it needs to meet fire safety standards? Is it so you would feel safer or something else?

Comment: Cast Perspex achieves a UK Class 3 fire rating. Extruded Perspex achieves a UK Class 4 fire rating.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, in this context, temporary means that it will be demolished soon.

Comment: what is an electric shower unit?  are you saying that your plastic covered floor is your shower?

Comment: Electric shower: a shower with its own on-demand electric water heater, sometimes actually located in the shower enclosure. Not something we see in the US, but apparently a common way elsewhere to retrofit buildings that were built with cold water only. (Americans can't quite believe anyone really thinks this is a good idea...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
Heavy flexible sheeting can be used to make a shower stall.  Just think like a raindrop and think like a roofer doing shingles.

As for fire code, forget it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no regulations or restrictions for temporary bathrooms.  You can do whatever you want.  What you propose seems fine, certainly better than newspapers (old roommate put newspaper in our bathroom to walk on so we didn't have to clean the floor - don't ask how it turned out).